# Number of roots of $2013x^{2012}-2012x^{2011}-16x+8=0$ in $[0,8^\frac1{2011}]$

Tags: functions, derivatives, roots, rolles-theorem

> If $P(x)=2013x^{2012}-2012x^{2011}-16x+8$, then $P(x)=0$ for $x\in\left[0,8^{\frac{1}{2011}}\right]$ has
>
> 1. exactly one real root.
> 2. no real root.
> 3. at least one and at most two real roots.
> 4. at least two real roots.

This question has answers [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1733308/if-px-2013x2012-2012x2011-16x8-then-px-0-for-x-in-left0-8-fra) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2353209/number-of-real-roots-of-2012-degree-equation-in-x-in-left0-8-frac12011?noredirect=1&lq=1).

I have doubts in them. I'll list that below.

**Answer$1:$**

Let $Q(x) = x^{2013} - x^{2012} -8x^2 +8x + c $. Note that $Q'(x)=P(x)$. Since $Q(0)=Q(1)=Q(8^\frac{1}{2011})$, we apply Rolle's Theorem to each of the intervals $[0,1]$ and $[1,8^\frac{1}{2011}]$ to conclude that $Q'(x)=P(x)$ has at least a root in each of the intervals $(0,1)$ and $(1,8^\frac{1}{2011})$. Hence $P(x)$ has at least two roots.

**Doubt:** How do we know $1\in(0,8^\frac1{2011})?$

**Answer$2:$**

$$\begin{align}P(x)&=2013x^{2012}-2012x^{2011}-16x+8  \\
P'(x)&=2013\cdot 2012x^{2011}-2012\cdot 2011x^{2010}-16\end{align}$$

$P'(0)$ is negative and $P'\left(8^{\frac{1}{2011}}\right)$ is positive. So $P'(x)$ has at least one real root.$\implies P(x)$ has at least two real roots.

**Doubt:** How do we know $P'(8^\frac1{2011})\gt0?$

**Answer$3:$**

We have $p(0)=8,p(1)=-7$ so there is at least one root in [0,1]. Put $\alpha=8^{1/2011}$. Then $p(\alpha)$ is approx 0. So we may have another root just inside the interval $[0,\alpha]$.

**Doubt:** How do we know $P(\alpha)$ is close to zero?

As I am typing this, I am realizing all my doubts are just regarding calculating the value at $x=8^\frac1{2011}$. I am not able to convincingly tell its value or sign, without using calculator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$x=8^{\frac {1}{2011}}$ means that $x^{2011}=8$.

If $x≤1$, then its 2011th power would only be smaller than or equal to 1, so we must have $1<x$.